# Python for each element in a list add the value of previous index and next index

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, range

For each element in a list I want to add the value before and after the element and append the result to an empty list. The problem is that at index 0 there is no index before and at the end there is no index next. At index 0 I want to add the value of index 0 with value of index 1, and in the last index I want to add the value of the last index with the same index value. As following:

```
vec = [1,2,3,4,5]
newVec = []

for i in range(len(vec)):
    newValue = vec[i] + vec[i+1] + vec[i-1]
    # if i + 1 or i - 1 does now exist pass 
    newVec.append(newValue)

 Expected output: newVec = [1+2, 2+1+3, 3+2+4,4+3+5,5+4]

 # newVec = [3, 6, 9, 12, 9]
```

Comment: with `i==0`and `i==len(vec)` you are able to test for cases where `i-1` or `i+1` do not exist. Then just create a condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have possible exceptions here, I think this code will do the trick and manage the exceptions.

```
vec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
new_vec = []
for index, number in enumerate(vec):
    new_value = number
    if index != 0:
        new_value += vec[index - 1]
    try:
        new_value += vec[index + 1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    new_vec.append(new_value)
```

Your output will look like this:

```
[3, 6, 9, 12, 9]
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 2):

You can make the conditions inside the for loop

```
for i in range(len(vec)):
    if i == 0 :
        newValue = vec[i] + vec[i+1]
    elif i == len(vec)-1:
        newValue = vec[i] + vec[i-1]
    else:
        newValue = vec[i] + vec[i+1] + vec[i-1]
    newVec.append(newValue)

print(newVec)
```

output:

```
[3, 6, 9, 12, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `0` to either side of `vec` so that it's adding nothing to create an accurate result. Then just use a `for i in range(1, ...)` loop, starting at value `1` to add value before and after `i`. This is what i got for my code:

```
vec = [1,2,3,4,5]
newVec = []
vec.insert(0, 0)
vec.insert(len(vec) + 1, 0)
for i in range(1, len(vec) - 1):
    newVec.append(vec[i-1] + vec[i] + vec[i+1])
print(newVec)
```

Which creates the output of:

> [3, 6, 9, 12, 9]

Hope this helps.